# Process Builder Formula for Case Status in Salesforce

Tags: community, formula, process-builder

In our Case process builder, we current have a step where the status is set automatically depending on the value of a custom picklist field.
The formula looks like this:

```
CASE([Case].CaseOutcome, 'Outcome A','Status A',
'Outcome B','Status A',
'Outcome C','Status B',
'Outcome D','Status C',
….
New)
```

There are three potential status types to be assigned and this formula, but a vast number of new outcomes have been added recently and we are in danger of breeching Process Builders 3900 character limit.

There are currently 85 outcomes to assign a status to;

```
55 will be given status A
20 will be given status B
10 will be given status C
```

What I am trying to do is change the formula so it will say something like this;

```
IF outcome = C, assign status B, ELSEIF outcome = D, assign status C, ELSE assign status A
```

I have managed an IF formula which will cover status B and A but not status C. Here is a sample of that formula;

```
IF((ISPICKVAL([Case].CaseOutcome__c, 'Outcome 1') || 
ISPICKVAL([Case].CaseOutcome__c, 'Outcome 2') ||
ISPICKVAL([Case].CaseOutcome__c, 'Outcome 3'),
'Status B', 'Status A')
```

This works perfectly EXCEPT, there is no way to assign status C.

I have looked through Salesforce formula documentation but haven't found a satisfactory solution. There doesn't seem to be an IF ELSEIF ELSE type formula, which is maddening and would be the exact solution I am looking for.

If anyone has encountered this issue themselves, I would love to hear how you got around it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can nest IF functions to something like this:

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL([Case].CaseOutcome__c, 'Outcome 1'),
        ISPICKVAL([Case].CaseOutcome__c, 'Outcome 2'),
        /* 
        * Other Status B Choices Here...
        */      
    ),
    'Status B',
    IF(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL([Case].CaseOutcome__c, 'Outcome 11'),
            ISPICKVAL([Case].CaseOutcome__c, 'Outcome 12'),
            /* 
            * Other Status C Choices Here...
            */
        ),
        'Status C',
        'Status A'
    )
)
```

This may still go over the limit depending on your available outcomes, and you may have to separate your logic into separate nodes and/or subprocesses, but the `IF`, `ELSE IF`, `ELSE` logic is handled here by nesting another `IF` function as the `ELSE` condition of the outer `IF`.